# Basic proof of $d\langle X\cdot M , Y\cdot N\rangle=XY\,d\langle M ,N\rangle$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

> How to proof that: $$\langle X\cdot M , Y\cdot N\rangle_T = \int^T_0 XY d \langle M, N\rangle$$ 
>   for $X,Y$ - simple processes and  $M,N \in M^2_c$.

If I need to prove that $$\langle X\cdot M \rangle_T = \int^T_0X^2 d \langle M\rangle$$ then knowing that DM decomposition tells us that:
$X^2 - \langle X\rangle$ is a martingale, I can take conditional expectation and show that: 
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[(X \cdot M)_T^2 - \langle X\cdot M \rangle_T - (X \cdot M)_S^2 + \langle X\cdot M \rangle_S | \mathcal{F}_S\right] = 0$$
**What is the way to deal with** **$\langle X\cdot M , Y\cdot N\rangle_T$?**

I suspect that working the same way I will get something similar, but I can not continue:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[(X \cdot M)_T(Y \cdot N)_T - \langle X\cdot M , Y\cdot N \rangle_T - (X \cdot M)_S(Y \cdot N)_S + \langle X\cdot M, Y\cdot N \rangle_S | \mathcal{F}_S\right] = 0$$
rewriting terms as martingale transforms. Is this a case when we consider simpler case and look at when $X=Y, M=N$?

Comment: Dear @Did, could you throw an idea how to proof that? Also, could you please share some experience on how to understand derivation of [plain stochastic integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176525/intuition-about-the-construction-of-a-stochastic-integral)  and maybe you may advise some [literature](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173587/literature-suggestions-stochastic-integration-for-intuition-for-non-mathemati) on the discipline?

Comment: What I could throw would mimick @saz's answer below (which I upvoted). Standard stuff, concisely explained.

Comment: Dear @Did, could you comment on other questions I am struggling to understand? I have posted links to them in my 1st comment here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Show (or recall) that the quadratic covariation satisfies $$\langle M,N \rangle_t = \frac{1}{4} \big( \langle M+N \rangle_t - \langle M-N \rangle_t \big) \tag{1}$$ for any two martingales $M,N \in \mathcal{M}_c^2$.
2. Use $(1)$ and the fact that $$\langle X \bullet M \rangle_t = \int_0^t X(s)^2 \, d\langle M \rangle_s$$ to show that $$\langle X \bullet M, Y \bullet M \rangle_t = \int_0^t X(s) Y(s) \, d\langle M \rangle_s. \tag{2} $$
3. Use $(2)$, $(1)$ and $$\begin{align*} \langle X \bullet M, Y \bullet N \rangle_t &= \frac{1}{4} \bigg( \langle X \bullet (M+N), Y \bullet (M+N) \rangle_t \\ &\qquad -  \langle X \bullet (M-N), Y \bullet (M-N) \rangle_t\bigg) \end{align*}$$ to conclude $$\langle X \bullet M, Y \bullet N \rangle_t = \int_0^t X(s) Y(s) \, d\langle M,N\rangle_s.$$

**Alternative approach:** Since $X$ and $Y$ are simple processes, the stochastic integrals $X \bullet M$ and $Y \bullet N$ can be calculcated explicitly. Then it is a straight-forward computation to verify that $$(X \bullet M)_t \cdot (Y \bullet N)_t - \int_0^t X(s) Y(s) \, d\langle M,N\rangle_s$$ is a martingale, and this proves the assertion.

Comment: Dear @saz, you were faster then me ;) wanted to fix typo with $N$. Thank you very much! It is a very elegant way to prove. Could you also give a hint, (maybe smaller) but how to prove in alternative approach? As I see it, I need to write down $X\bullet M$ as a sum, hence: $$(X\bullet M)_t(Y\bullet N)_t = \sum^\infty \xi_i( M_{t\wedge t_{i+1}}- M_{t\wedge t_{i}} ) \sum^\infty \xi^*_i( N_{t\wedge t_{i+1}}- N_{t\wedge t_{i}} )$$ but it gets cumbersome. Is that a correct way?

Comment: @StochasticIntegrationStudent Essentially, the idea is to use that $$\mathbb{E}((M_t-M_r)(N_t-N_r) \mid \mathcal{F}_r) = \mathbb{E}(\langle M,N \rangle_t - \langle M,N \rangle_r \mid \mathcal{F}_r) \tag{3}$$ for all $r \leq t$. If you condition the product of the integrals on, say, $\mathcal{F}_s$, then you can pull outside all the terms with $t_{i+1} \leq s$; for the other terms use the tower property to condition on $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$ and use $(3)$ (with $r=t_i$) and the fact that $\xi_i$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$-measurable.