# Crossvariation computation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are continuous martingales, $K$ and $H$ are processes that can be written in the form:
$$
K_s = \sum_{i=0}^p Y_{a_i}\mathbb{1}_{(a_i,a_{i+1}]}(s),\quad H_s = \sum_{j=0}^q X_{a_j}\mathbb{1}_{(a_j,a_{j+1}]}(s)
$$
with each $Y_{a_i}$ $\mathcal{F}_{a_i}$-measurable. For such processes we define:
$$
\int_0^t K_s dM_s = \sum_{i=0}^p Y_{a_i}(M_{t \land a_{i+1}}-M_{t \land a_i})
$$
I'm trying to compute the cross-variation
$$
\left\langle \int_0^{.} K_s dM_s,\int_0^{.} H_s dN_s  \right\rangle_t
$$
but I get lost in the computation of:
$$
\left\langle \sum_{i=0}^p Y_{a_i}(M_{\cdot \land a_{i+1}} - M_{\cdot \land a_{i}}) ,\sum_{j=0}^q X_{a_j}(N_{\cdot \land a_{j+1}} - N_{\cdot \land a_{j}})\right\rangle_t
$$
obtaining something like:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^p \sum_{j=0}^q Y_{a_i}X_{a_j}\langle M_{\cdot \land a_{i+1}} - M_{\cdot \land a_{i}}, N_{\cdot \land a_{j+1}} - N_{\cdot \land a_{j}} \rangle_t
$$
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. The result should be:
$$ 
\int_0^t K_s H_s d \langle M, N \rangle_s
$$

Comment: Somewhere you dropped the $t\wedge$ from $M_{t\wedge\, a_i}$ etc. You should figure out what $\langle M_{\,\cdot\,\wedge\, a_i}-M_{\,\cdot\,\wedge \,a_{i+1}},N_{\,\cdot\,\wedge\, a_i}-N_{\,\cdot\,\wedge\, a_{i+1}}\rangle_t$ is.

Comment: @KurtG. That's indeed my difficulty. I notice you used only the $i$ index, but a priori the $a_i$ and $a_j$ should be allowed to be different, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177666/basic-proof-of-d-langle-x-cdot-m-y-cdot-n-rangle-xy-d-langle-m-n-rangle?rq=1). In the answer there your approach is suggested as an alternative but the details are left as an exercise. Does the following help? The product of your stochastic integrals is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^p\sum_{j=0}^q 
Y_{a_i}X_{a_j} 
(M_{t \wedge a_{i+1}} - M_{t \wedge a_{i}})
(N_{t \wedge a_{j+1}} - N_{t \wedge a_{j}})\,. 
$$
For each $t$ there is a unique pair $(k,l)$ such that this is
$$
\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \sum_{j=0}^{l-1} Y_{a_i}X_{a_j} (M_{a_{i+1}} - M_{a_i})(N_{a_{j+1}} - N_{a_j})}_{=:Z_{k,l}}+Y_{a_k}X_{a_l} (M_t - M_{a_k})(N_{t} - N_{a_l})\,. 
$$
This is clearly of the form
$$
Z_{k,l}+Y_{a_k}X_{a_l} (M_tN_t - M_{a_k}N_t - N_{a_l}M_t+M_{a_k}N_{a_l}).
$$
The process with bounded variation that we have to subtract from this to make it a martingale is obviously
$$
Z_{k,l}+Y_{a_k}X_{a_l} (\langle M,N\rangle_t+M_{a_k}N_{a_l}).
$$